# react-query: onSuccess, onError, onSettled are deprecated. What should I use instead?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

In this code snippet, when I hover over the `onSuccess` callback, it says that it's deprecated and will be removed in the next major version. The same happens with `onError` and `onSettled` callbacks. What do I use instead?

```
  const { isError, error, data, refetch, isFetching } = useQuery(
    ["posts"],
    fetchPosts,
    { enabled: false, onSuccess: () => {} }
  );
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

## `onError`

You can use the `onError` callback inside the `queryCache` option of `QueryClient`

```
import {
  QueryCache,
  QueryClient,
} from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  queryCache: new QueryCache({
    onError: (error) => {
      toast(`Something went wrong: ${error.message}`),
    }
  }),
})
```

And then wrap your application with it like you normally would:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <Posts />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  )
}
```

If you need more customizable `onError` side effects, then use the `meta` option of the `useQuery` hook. You can pass it any data you want, which you can then use to determine which side effect to trigger.

I came up with this solution:

Define an enum containing the error codes for triggering the side effects:

```
export const enum TErrCodes {
  POSTS_FETCH_FAILED,
  // other error codes...
}
```

Specify the error code in the `meta` option of the `useQuery` hook:

```
const query = useQuery(["posts"], fetchPosts, {
  meta: { errCode: TErrCodes.POSTS_FETCH_FAILED },
});
```

Detect the error code in the `queryCache` `onError` callback and perform the side effect you need. I'm showing notifications using the `react-toastify` library as an example:

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  queryCache: new QueryCache({
    onError: queryCacheOnError,
  }),
});

function queryCacheOnError(err: unknown, query: Query) {
  switch (query.meta?.errCode) {
    case TErrCodes.POSTS_FETCH_FAILED:
      return toast.error("Could not fetch posts");
    default:
      return toast.error("Something went wrong");
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can trigger `onError` side effects from the query function, like so:

```
async function fetchPosts() {
  try {
    const resp = await axios.get<TPost[]>("/posts");
    return resp.data;
  } catch (err) {
    if (!isKnownErr(err)) {
      return toast("Something went wrong");
    }

    switch (err.response.data.errCode) {
      case "INVALID_CREDENTIALS":
        toast("Invalid sign-in credentials");
        break;
      // more cases...
      default:
        toast("Something went wrong");
    }

    throw new Error(); // prevent query from being successful
  }
}

const query = useQuery(["posts"], fetchPosts);
```

## `onSuccess`

You can trigger the `onSuccess` side-effects from inside the query function as well, like this:

```
async function fetchPosts() {
  const resp = await axios.get<TPost[]>("/postss");
  yourSideEffect();
  return resp.data;
}
const query = useQuery(["posts"], fetchPosts);
```

### Why were they removed in the first place?

This is mostly taken from [this article](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/breaking-react-querys-api-on-purpose)

1. The callbacks have inconsistent behavior. They can be called multiple times for the same query, leading to duplication of side effects or state updates. For example, this can lead to showing 2 duplicate error notifications for the same query.
2. The callbacks have been misused by some developers to perform state syncing operations, which often leads to really hard-to-spot bugs. You should instead derive state by using something like `const postsCount = posts.length;`. The `postsCount` variable will be updated whenever the component re-renders.
3. Using callbacks sometimes leads to unexpected behavior with redux and other state managers.

Here's [another article](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-error-handling) on the topic

Hope you found this helpful!

Comment: How would you invalidate the query cache from another function? I have my API calling methods separated from my component code in order to test them well. So I can't use the `useQueryClient();` hook in order to invalidate the cache. E.g with `queryClient.invalidateQueries(["products"]);`

Comment: i could give you a better answer if you shared the code, but from the context, maybe you could invalidate the query outside of the API calling function?

Comment: there are a couple of more reads on this
https://tkdodo.eu/blog/breaking-react-querys-api-on-purpose  and 
https://github.com/TanStack/query/discussions/5279

Comment: @Florent what implementation did you go ahead with to invalidateQueries?

Comment: @tobias for the `useMutation` hooks I didn't change anything since only `useQuery` will change. For that I just changed the way I call my function. Instead of just providing the function, I rewrote everything to .. async () => {await fetchPosts(); queryClient.invalidate();}.. in addition to the propsed solution, it works fine

Comment: What if I want to use result of error inside the component?