# react-query: onError. What should I use instead?

Tags: reactjs, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I have the same problem as here [react-query: onSuccess, onError, onSettled are deprecated. What should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76961108/react-query-onsuccess-onerror-onsettled-are-deprecated-what-should-i-use-ins) . And the the proposed solution is good but what if I want to use the result of the error inside the component? What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your particular use case has something more complex, consider using useEffect with error in dependencies.

Here is the blog post about changes in `tanstack/react-query`:
https://tkdodo.eu/blog/breaking-react-querys-api-on-purpose#a-bad-api

Answer (score 1):

> what if I want to use the result of the error inside the component?

That has always been returned from `useQuery`:

```
const { error } = useQuery(...)

if (error) {
  return <div>error: {error.message}</div>
}
```

So not sure what this has to do with the callbacks?

Comment: What if I want to setSomeStateVariable if I get an error from useQuery?

Comment: That's usually an anti pattern and one of the reasons why the callbacks were removed, so I would ask why you want to do that?

Comment: I want to get error.response.data and set to state variable and then use in the code

Comment: Like I said, you don't need it in state because it is returned as `error` from `useQuery`